# How can reorder this array in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have this:

```
list = [[apple, John], [apple, Paul], [banana, Paul]]
```

to be like this:

```
list = [[apple, [John, Paul]], [banana, [Paul]]
```

I don't know how to solve this issue because I need to know the frequency of each element and reorder them according to the whole list...

Comment: Your datastructures are not valid Ruby datastructures. Also, what have you tried? [so] is for helping you solve problems with the code you write, not for writing your code for you! Please, provide a [mcve], specification of the desired inputs and outputs, including corner cases and exceptions. Give examples of valid inputs and the desired outputs, including ones that demonstrate the corner cases. Maybe read the [help/on-topic], look into [ask], take the [tour] and look through [meta].

Comment: You may wish to use a hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list.group_by(&:first).map { |fruit, preferences| [fruit, preferences.map(&:last)] }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = [["apple", "John"], ["apple", "Paul"], ["banana", "Paul"]]  
=> [["apple", "John"], ["apple", "Paul"], ["banana", "Paul"]]
```

Using [Enumberable#each_with_object](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/each_with_object), aggregating all values on the basis of key in hash, and then converting back to array

```
list.each_with_object(Hash.new{[]}) { |x, h| h[x.first] <<= x.last }.to_a
=> [["apple", ["John", "Paul"]], ["banana", ["Paul"]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way.

```
list = [%w|apple John|, %w|apple Paul|, %w|banana Paul|]
  #=> [["apple", "John"], ["apple", "Paul"], ["banana", "Paul"]]

list.each_with_object({}) { |(fruit,name),h| h.update(fruit=>[name]) { |_k,o,n| o+n } }
  #=> {"apple"=>["John", "Paul"], "banana"=>["Paul"]}
```

This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs a block (`{ |_k,o,n| o+n }`) to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. See the doc for the definitions of the three block variables, `_k`, `o` and `n`. The underscore tells the reader that `_k` (often written just `_`) is not used in the block calculation.